# Small modification to my jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello how can I edit my following code to reload automatically the content of a specified div?

My code below reloads a file called form.php and I would like to be replaced with a div.

```
<style>
    .loading { 
        height:24px; 
        background: url('http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yb/r/GsNJNwuI-UM.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat; 
        }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script language='JavaScript'>
setInterval( 'SANAjax();', 10000 );  ///////// 10 seconds

$(function() 
{
    SANAjax = function()
    {     
        $('#reservationdetails')
            .empty()
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('form.php', function()
            {
                $('#reservationdetails').removeClass('loading') 
            });

    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The title of this post is extremely bad. It is really no better than "help me" or "fix my code", especially since we can already see it's jQuery from the tags. You should consider editing your question to fix the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reorder your code:

```
$(function() {
    var SANAjax = function(){
        $('#reservationdetails').empty().addClass('loading')
          .load('form.php', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('loading') 
          });
    }
    setInterval(SANAjax, 10000 );
});
```

I assumed that `#reservationdetails` is the div you want to load the responce in.

There is no need to pass a string to `setInterval`. Always pass function reference to it (same for `setTimeout`).

Comment: Thank you for this! Can I reload the contents of a div without having a file to be loaded? That's because inside that div there is a script that gets some results and creating a new php file with it in, it's not an option.

Comment: Hi Felix, How can I load the page on body load and just continue with the 10000 interval? Because it takes some time to load it at first.

Comment: @Punkis: Just call `SANAjax();`.

Answer (score 2):

Felix Kling's answer is correct.

Also worth noting: it is very bad practice to use `setInterval` in this manner, as you are unsure if `.load` will return within the 10 seconds you specified. (Think, for example, of mobile devices.) Even if it did return in 9 seconds, it would then be only one second before you fired off the next request. Better to do a `setTimeout` in the callback, like so:

```
$(function () {
    function loadReservationDetails() {
        $('#reservationdetails')
            .empty()
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('form.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                setTimeout(loadReservationDetails, 10000);
        });
    }

    loadReservationDetails();
});
```

Comment: Hi Domenic, How can I load the page on body load and just continue with the 10000 interval? Because it takes some time to load it at first.